# Promise.all for array.map with axios

Tags: javascript, promise, axios, es6-promise

**What I would like to do:**
I have an array of book titles. e.g.

```
var bookTitleArray = ["1984", "clockwork Orange"];
```

For this array I would like to call an API via axios and get back detail info on each title.

**What I have done so far:**
To do so, I have created an array.map request which calls axios which is wrapped into an async function.

The axios async function looks like following:

```
async function axiosWrapper (Item){
    var ItemPromise = axios.request({
            url: 'some URL',
            method: 'get',
            baseURL: 'some URL',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'some authorization'
            }
          })
    var axiosResult = await ItemPromise;
    return axiosResult
}
```

I have console.logged the axiosResult and it delivers the right data back. Hence the axios seems to work

The async with the promise.all looks as following:

```
async function mapWrapper(ArrayToRunThrough){

    var promiseArray = ArrayToRunThrough.map(Item => {
        axiosWrapper(Item)
    })

    var ArrayOfResults = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
    console.log(ArrayOfResults);
}
```

In the end I invoke the mapWrapper with the array of books I would like to search

```
mapWrapper(bookTitleArray)
```

**What I experienced:** Unfortunately I get back only two arrays of "undefined".

**My assumption:** I assume the Promise.all / await to not work as expected.

**Where I need help:** How can I get the actual values from the Axios API call in this setup in the "ArrayOfResults"?

Comment: When arrow functions have a block body, ie `=>{...}` you need to explicitly do a `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning your `axiosWrapper` in your `map`. 
You should do :

```
async function mapWrapper(ArrayToRunThrough){

    var promiseArray = ArrayToRunThrough.map(Item => {
        return axiosWrapper(Item)
    })

    var ArrayOfResults = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
    console.log(ArrayOfResults);
}
```

Comment: Bingo, that's it. Thank you so much. I thought that this would not be necessary as the axisWrapper (Item) provides back a promise by itself which is then used in the map function

Comment: If I then would like to access the `ArrayOfResults` after I have invoked `mapWrapper(bookTitleArray)` I would place `return ArrayOfResults` after `console.log(ArrayOfResults)` and then would await the result of the function like `resultsToWorkWith = await mapWrapper(bookTitleArray)`. This again would mean, that I also have to wrap the `mapWrapper` in an async function as well. Or would there be a more elegant way to access the `resultsToWorkWith`?

Comment: @Geole yes exactly ! But watch out you can only use `await` in an `async` function.